# Unique input value in Angular using Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have the following code in my html, I am trying to let a user input a value in the input field and then get the value in my ts file. However when I type in one input field, the other input fields below also get populated. I need only the input field where the user is typing in to get populated. Any thoughts

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="branch_code">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Enter Branch Code</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <input matInput placeholder="Enter Branch Code" [(ngModel)]="branchCode">
      <mat-icon (click)="gotoWorkstationDetails()" >arrow_forward</mat-icon>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

I can get the input value successfully in my ts file.

Please see screenshot for visual. All input fields are getting '213'. It must only display in my active input field
[image]

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-workstation',
  templateUrl: './workstation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./workstation.component.scss']
})
export class WorkstationComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Workstation';


  displayedColumns = ['name', 'mac_address', 'address', 'branch_code'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  loading = false;
  branchCode;

  constructor( private http: HttpClient, public router: Router ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.loading = true;
    this.http.get<Array<any>>('/api/workstations').subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
      this.loading = false;
    },
    err => {
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim();
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  gotoWorkstationDetails() {
    console.log(this.branchCode);

    this.loading = true;
    this.http.get<Array<any>>(`/api/branches/${this.branchCode}/workstations`).subscribe(data => {
      const branchDetail = data;
      this.router.navigate(['workstation/' + this.branchCode]);
      console.log(branchDetail);
      this.loading = false;
    },
      err => {
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Input in data table](https://input-in-data-table.stackblitz.io)

Create one more data column like `branchCode` in table :

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="branch_code">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Enter Branch Code</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <input matInput placeholder="Enter Branch Code" [(ngModel)]="row.branchCode">
        <mat-icon (click)="gotoWorkstationDetails()">arrow_forward</mat-icon>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Here you are referencing `branchCode` to all input.

Comment: thanks this solves the input into a specific field, but now how do I get the value into my ts file. I am getting an undefined in console. It worked previously. I am using a click event to get the value

Comment: share you ts please complete.

Comment: Use this.dataSource.data

Comment: Go to demo link check the demo

Comment: Yes this works, thank you very much. I also found a less effective way of doing it by passing row.branchCode as an event in the click function

Comment: welcome. ping me back if any help required in future as well.